# Json ajax with parameter passing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

```
function BindJson() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "NewPage.aspx/SerializeJson",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data1) {
                alert(data1);
            }
        })
    }
    [WebMethod]
        public static string SerializeJson()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            //Person p2 = js.Deserialize<Person>(str);
            return "";
        }
```

How do I pass parameters as data to my serializeJson function?

Comment: put the json in the data parameter

Comment: I want to pass json data which is as follows:-

{ "firstName": "Denny", "lastName": "Cherian", "department": "Microsoft PSS", "address": { "addressline1": "Microsoft India GTSC", "addressline2": "PSS - DSI", "city": "Bangalore", "state": "Karnataka", "country": "India", "pin": 560028 }, "technologies": ["IIS", "ASP.NET", "JavaScript", "AJAX"] }

Comment: These values are from html controls?

Comment: Nope. I have stored them in a variable

Comment: You mean as javascript object? or just a variable for each value?

Comment: i have stored that in var str.

Comment: Frankly speaking I dont really know what I am doing. When can I use Json to serialize and deserialize? Could anyone help me.

Comment: Wondering why are you doing like that? how you formed this string?
You shd have got all these values from a html page right? Could you please post the html page too?

Comment: Please go through the link i have posted!!

Comment: Sorry. Could you help me with a nice article to read on json serialize and deserialize? I dont want to proceed further with the example

Comment: I have updated my answer, go through the article

Comment: Thanks but no thanks everyone. I have found the solution to my answer. I appreciate the spirit.

Comment: @sly_Chandan: You should share your solution here so that others can benefit from it.

Comment: @sly - why not share your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work for you (full working code sample below).  The key is to pass in a Person object. Also, I used a simple web service (myService.asmx) instead of an aspx page.  Why bother with the extra overhead if it isn't needed?

The key is, on the client, create a Person object and then use [JSON.stringify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to pass the Person object to the webservice.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BindJson() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myService.asmx/SerializeJson",
            data: JSON.stringify({ person:{ firstName: "Denny", lastName: "Cherian", department: "Microsoft PSS", address: { addressline1: "Microsoft India GTSC", addressline2: "PSS - DSI", city: "Bangalore", state: "Karnataka", country: "India", pin: "560028" }, technologies: ["IIS", "ASP.NET", "JavaScript", "AJAX"] }}),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data1) {
                alert(data1.d);
            },
            error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        BindJson();    
    });
</script>
```

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace TestProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for myService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class myService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string SerializeJson(Person person)
        {
            return "Success";
        }

        public class Person
        {
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string department { get; set; }
            public Address address { get; set; }
            public string[] technologies { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
            public string addressline1 { get; set; }
            public string addressline2 { get; set; }
            public string city { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string pin { get; set; }            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method that jQuery offers to pass the data.

Please see this [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=435)

Comment: Why give me a post on hijacking?